# Use onslide together with tcolorbox to show four pictures on the same slide

Tags: beamer, presentations

My problem is that, I've two columns slides that contain `tcolorbox` of each side which in turn include a figure. I tried using the `\onslide` command to show the four picures.
This my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{tikz}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg,.eps}
\usepackage{epsfig} 
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\graphicspath{{./figs/}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Robotic Arm Applications}

    %   Robotic arms are typically used in industry. Their  applications include:
    \begin{columns}[c]
        %       \onslide<-2>{

            \column{2.2in}
            \onslide<1->\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,colback={green},title={  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.65\textheight]{Robot_welding}},colbacktitle=yellow,coltitle=blue,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=1mm,arc=0mm,boxrule=0.5pt]
                \centering In Welding
            \end{tcolorbox} 

            \onslide<3->\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,colback={green},title={      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.65\textheight]{Robot_medical}},colbacktitle=yellow,coltitle=blue,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=1mm,arc=0mm,boxrule=0.5pt]    
                \centering In Medical
            \end{tcolorbox}
            %               }
            %       \onslide<-1>{
            \column{2.2in}
            \onslide<2->\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,colback={green},title={      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.65\textheight]{Robot_handling}},colbacktitle=yellow,coltitle=blue,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=1mm,arc=0mm,boxrule=0.5pt]    
                \centering Material Handling
            \end{tcolorbox} 
            %               }

            \onslide<4->\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,colback={green},title={  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.65\textheight]{Robot_automotive}},colbacktitle=yellow,coltitle=blue,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=1mm,arc=0mm,boxrule=0.5pt]    
                \centering Automotive Industry
            \end{tcolorbox}

        \end{columns}
        %------------------

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what problem you want to solve here? Your example works for me with exception of the image height `0.65\textheight` which is chosen too large.

Comment: @ Thomas, yes it is working, but the problem is that, the last two pictures are shown on the bottom of the previous ones. I want to remove the first two and display the last two in their place, on the same slide, with the same height of `0.65\textheight`. I hope you got my point.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. I posted an answer for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to replace `\onslide` by `\only` which does not cover space in the uncovered case. Also, the overlay specification has to be modified slightly.

This gives:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{tikz}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg,.eps}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\graphicspath{{./figs/}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Robotic Arm Applications}

    %   Robotic arms are typically used in industry. Their  applications include:
    \begin{columns}[c]
%
            \column{2.2in}%
            \only<1-2>{\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,colback={green},title={  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.65\textheight]{example-image-a}},colbacktitle=yellow,coltitle=blue,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=1mm,arc=0mm,boxrule=0.5pt]
                \centering In Welding
            \end{tcolorbox}}%
%
            \only<3->{\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,colback={green},title={      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.65\textheight]{example-image-b}},colbacktitle=yellow,coltitle=blue,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=1mm,arc=0mm,boxrule=0.5pt]
                \centering In Medical
            \end{tcolorbox}}%
%
            \column{2.2in}%
            \only<2-3>{\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,colback={green},title={      \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.65\textheight]{example-image-c}},colbacktitle=yellow,coltitle=blue,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=1mm,arc=0mm,boxrule=0.5pt]
                \centering Material Handling
            \end{tcolorbox}}%
%
            \only<4->{\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\textwidth,colback={green},title={  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.65\textheight]{example-image-a}},colbacktitle=yellow,coltitle=blue,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=1mm,arc=0mm,boxrule=0.5pt]
                \centering Automotive Industry
            \end{tcolorbox}}%
%
        \end{columns}
        %------------------

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One last point, is there any way to decrease or remove the vertical spacing between the figure and frame title, or should I post another question, for this.

Comment: @AlFagera This spacing is caused by `boxsep=1mm`. With `boxsep=0mm` the yellow frame will vanish completely, but also the spacing in the text field. But then, you can add `top`, `bottom`, `toptitle`, `bottomtitle` to set individual spacings.